# React: detect when all children components have been loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing an implementation in which I need to detect when all children components have been loaded, from a multi-level hierarchy.
Example: MAIN component have a WORKSPACE component, which can have multiple COLUMN components and each COLUMN can have multiple WIDGET components.

Each widget is rendered after ajax calls (have to fetch some data in the server).

I need to detect when all WIDGETs components have been loaded (after async calls) in MAIN component.
I do not know which is the best approach/pattern to do this.

I know I can use some callbacks in each component to tell the parent that the component is loaded and then do this recursively, but I'm looking for a solution that solves this without having to deal with each level of the hierarchy.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want this to happen? Maybe you have to rethink your architecture slightly. You could have a state where you count components that have received their data successfully.

Comment: [**_compoenentDidMount ?_**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)